# How do I store a pointer to a template in scala Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

In Scala with Play Framework 2 I would like to store a template that I will render later. Here is a code example:

```
trait TraitController {
    self:Controller =>
    var indexTemplate = null // This is the variable I would like to 
                             // store the template pointer.
    def index()  = Action { 
        var user :User
        var context :Context
            ... 

            OK(indexTemplate(user, context))
        }

object MyController extends Controller with TraitController {
    indexTemplate = views.html.Index
}
```

The routes file has an entry in it that looks like

```
GET     /index              controllers.MyController.index()
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

**Bonus Marks:** How could I find a template given a string. Example:
    var indexTemplate: Template = Template("views.html.Index")
    OK(indexTemplate(user, context))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `indexTemplate` an `abstract def` that would be implemented by any `Controller` that extends it:

```
trait TraitController {
    self: Controller =>

    def indexTemplate(user: User, context: Context): Html

    def index()  = Action { 
        ... 
        Ok(indexTemplate(user, context))
    }
}

object MyController extends Controller with TraitController {
    def indexTemplate(user: User, context: Context): Html = views.html.Index(user, context)
}
```

This is similar to the `ViewTemplates` pattern used by [Secure Social](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers/ViewsPlugin.scala), except they use an entire trait to inject the implemented templates.

Comment: Thanks! This is the pattern I am using now.